# UIWebView crashes when touching any inputs for logging details

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I added a simple in-app UIWebView feature. I noticed that when ever I touch an input box to enter login details (facebook login,twitter login, forums login,etc) the application crashes. I have tried on more than one device. I even created a new project to test it out and the app still crashes.

Is there some restrictions on UIWebView from Apple ?

Note: I would post the UIWebView code but it's simple and popular and I'm posting my Q from my iPhone. Will post any if you ask.

Comment: I think it is not the problem of UIWebView, the actual problem could have been covered. It is probable that Interface Builder is not properly used...

Comment: Will provide as soon as I get back home!